# I want to get the duplicate tag_name arrays to group under one array

Tags: php, arrays

From this below array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag_name] => Quant-Arithmetic
            [student_marks] => 1.05
            [total_marks] => 2.00
            [student_count] => 1
            [level] => Easy
            [overall_percentage] => 52
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tag_name] => Quant-Arithmetic
            [student_marks] => 1.10
            [total_marks] => 4.00
            [student_count] => 1
            [level] => Medium
            [overall_percentage] => 28
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tag_name] => Quant-Algebra
            [student_marks] => 0.20
            [total_marks] => 1.00
            [student_count] => 1
            [level] => Easy
            [overall_percentage] => 20
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [tag_name] => Quant-Algebra
            [student_marks] => 1.00
            [total_marks] => 6.00
            [student_count] => 1
            [level] => Medium
            [overall_percentage] => 17
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [tag_name] => Quant-Algebra
            [student_marks] => 1.50
            [total_marks] => 6.00
            [student_count] => 1
            [level] => Hard
            [overall_percentage] => 25
        )

)
```

To some thing similar: As i need an array based on tag name with its all levels inside that array so that I can get the individual tag name with its level and percentage for further calculations

```
[tag_name]
{
 [level]:[overall_percentage]
 [level]:[overall_percentage]
 .
 .
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: what you WANT? JSON or array?

Comment: Both JSON and Array here: [https://3v4l.org/boNIK](https://3v4l.org/boNIK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
$array =array
(
  '0' => array
    (
        'tag_name' => 'Quant-Arithmetic',
        'student_marks' => ' 1.05',
        'total_marks' => ' 2.00',
        'student_count' => ' 1',
        'level' => ' Easy',
        'overall_percentage' => ' 52',
    ),

'1' => array
    (
        'tag_name' => ' Quant-Arithmetic',
        'student_marks' => ' 1.10',
        'total_marks' => ' 4.00',
        'student_count' => ' 1',
        'level' => ' Medium',
        'overall_percentage' => ' 28',
    ),

'2' => array
    (
        'tag_name' => ' Quant-Algebra',
        'student_marks' => ' 0.20',
        'total_marks' => ' 1.00',
        'student_count' => ' 1',
        'level' => ' Easy',
        'overall_percentage' => ' 20',
    )
    );
    // declare a new array
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $values){
  // trim array elements
  $trimmed_array=array_map('trim',$values);
  if(isset($new_array[$trimmed_array['tag_name']])){
    //add elements to array
    $new_array[$trimmed_array['tag_name']][$trimmed_array['level']] = $trimmed_array['overall_percentage'];
}else{
    // create new array
    $new_array[$trimmed_array['tag_name']] = array($trimmed_array['level'] => $trimmed_array['overall_percentage']);
  }
}

// php array
print_r($new_array);
// json
echo json_encode($new_array);
```

Out Put :  array

```
Array
(
[Quant-Arithmetic] => Array
    (
        [Easy] => 52
        [Medium] => 28
    )

[Quant-Algebra] => Array
    (
        [Easy] => 20
    )
```

)

Out Put : Json

```
{"Quant-Arithmetic":{"Easy":"52","Medium":"28"},"Quant-Algebra":{"Easy":"20"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $newArray = array();
 foreach($yourarray as $item){
    $newArray[$item['tag_name']][$item['level']] = $item['overall_percentage'];
 }
```

This will add create a $newArray as follows:

```
 Array(
    'tag_name' => Array(
        'Medium' => '27'
     )
 )
```

Comment: are you sure this is what OP want?

Comment: I think your loop is perfect but not the output.

Comment: I have edited my response. My original included an extra array level depth because I was under the impression that there would be multiple levels with the same key value (E.g. 2x Easy)